# pjax vs turbolinks vs cache_digests to improve rails speed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, performance, caching

I've done some reading about the various options for improving the speed of a rails site.

The following libraries seem promising:

- pjax
- turbolinks
- cache_digests

However, it seems like they try to do many similar things.

Can/Should you use them in tandem? Are there problems that would arise in doing so?

Are there cases where one or the other is better than the rest? (And what are they?)

Is there something superior to all three I should check out instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cache_digests is not something that can be compared with pjax or turbolinks.
cache_digests enhances Rails caching to allow for Russian-doll caching.

Turbolinks tends to be a bit more straightforward and doesn't require jquery.

Pjax is configurable but required jquery.

Comment: So then would you suggest (pjax OR turbo links) AND cache_digests ?

Comment: It depends on your application needs.  Just installed cache_digests will do nothing for you.  Here is a Railscasts on cache_digets - http://railscasts.com/episodes/387-cache-digests

If you are going to setup caching in your application, then yes, use both.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer pjax. It's easy to use and very fast. You just have to define a pjax-container which will be replaced every request.

Turbolinks instead does replace the whole body. I don't like that very much. But that's matter of taste. It will be part of Rails 4.

Comment: Like cpuguy83 says, cache_digests is something different. if you want to just change a part of your layout go with pjax otherwise try turbolinks.